# Cron Job executes even after deleting cron jobs

Tags: linux, centos, cron, centos-7

I delete all of my cron jobs on my amazon ec2 instance, 
but for some reason the shutting down cron (i shut down another ec2 instance) still executes on a specific time.

I deleted all cron jobs using:

> sudo crontab -r

and checked if any cron job exists:

> for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; sudo crontab -u $user -l; done

I see zero cron job for any user.

How could a cron job execute if it does not exist or it hidden somewhere.

Please help.

Comment: Anything relevant in `/etc/cron.(daily|weekly|monthly)/` directories or in `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: There are some files there like in cron.hourly: "0anacron"  and  in cron.daily: "logrotate" and  "man-db.cron". crontab contains some info how to use cron and Path/Shell stuff

Comment: What to look for exactly there?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the cron logs to find out exactly which cron is being run and the path of the cron and where its set. You can debug it from there.